# Game of Nim, computer will not make move

Tags: java

I am attempting to make a Game of Nim for a school project, but whenever the computer attempts to make its move, it will not actually do anything unless there is three or less rocks left. My temp code will also execute in the console, so it runs through it, its just not working.

These are the custom voids:

```
public void winnerCheck(){
    if(rocksLeft == 0 && lastPlayer == 0){
        logBox.append("Plose gameOver");
    }else if(rocksLeft == 0 && lastPlayer == 1){
        logBox.append("Close gameOver");
    }
    //temp
    System.out.println("winnerCheck() successful");
}

public void playersMove() throws BadLocationException{
    lastPlayer = 0;
    //used to gather players input and attempt to make a move
    try{
        playersRocks = Integer.parseInt(txtfPlayer.getText());
        if(playersRocks <= 3 && playersRocks>=1){
            rocksLeft -= playersRocks;
            logBox.append("You have taken "+playersRocks+" rocks.\nThere are: "+rocksLeft+" rocks left.\nIt is the computer's turn.\n\n");
        }else{
            isValid = false;
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        isValid = false;
    }
    //temp
    System.out.println("playersMove() successful");
}

public void computerAttempt(int computersRocks){
    //this void is a snippet for the computer trying to make a play.
    //contains only outputs and rocksLeft altering equation
    logBox.append("\nThe computer is making a play.\n");
    try {
        //makes the game feel more realistic, as the computer takes time to make a move.
        Thread.sleep(1600);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GameOfNim.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    rocksLeft -= computersRocks;
    logBox.append("The computer has taken "+computersRocks+" rocks.\nThere are: "+rocksLeft+" rocks left.\nIt is your turn!\n\n");
}

public void computersMove() throws BadLocationException{
    lastPlayer = 1;
    //computer will attempt to win, if not possible at the time it will take a random number
    if(rocksLeft == 3){
        computerAttempt(2);

    }else if(rocksLeft == 2){
        computerAttempt(1);

    }else if(rocksLeft == 1){
        logBox.append("The computer takes 1 rock.\n There are: 0 rocks left.\n\n Y O U    H A V E    W O N\n\n");

    }else if(rocksLeft > 3){
    computersRocks = (int) (Math.random()*(3-1+1)+1);
    }
    //temp
    System.out.println("computersMove() succesful");
}
```

These are the two buttons:

```
private void buttonStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    //starts/resets game    
    rocksLeft = (int)(Math.random()*(30-15+1)+15);
    buttonStart.setText("Reset");
    buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
    logBox.setText("T h e   g a m e   h a s   b e g u n !\n\nThere are: "+rocksLeft+" rocks left.\nIt is your turn!\n\n");
}                                           

private void buttonPlayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    //check if game is over
    if(rocksLeft == 0){
        logBox.append("The game has completed!\n Press the reset button to play again!");
        System.out.println("gameOver succesful");
    }else{
        try {
            //allows each player to move then checks if the player won or not
            playersMove();
            winnerCheck();
            computersMove();
            winnerCheck();
            //temp
            System.out.println("buttonPlay() succesful\n");
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GameOfNim.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
}
```

[image: The computer never attempts to make a move unless there is 3 or less rocks left]

Comment: What specifically is the failure here?

Comment: I added a pciture of the failure, the computer never actually attempts to make the random move, (taking a random number of rocks from 1 -3 ), but when there is 3 or less rocks left, it will make a move to win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the game you are making, but here is your mistake I think.
If there are more than 3 rocks left, you call

```
   }else if(rocksLeft > 3){
computersRocks = (int) (Math.random()*(3-1+1)+1);
}
```

Which, I think, should be

```
   }else if(rocksLeft > 3){
computerAttempt((int) (Math.random()*(3-1+1)+1));
}
```

Because you just changed the variable without calling the method on the value.(And I presume the important variable is the 'rocksLeft' which never got changed in your code, when the value was > 3.